# Laravel get date between specifics days

Tags: laravel

Hello everyone is there anyway in Laravel to get the last 2 weeks starting from Wednesday to Wednesday
e.g. From 6 Wednesday, April 6, 2022 to Wednesday, April 20, 2022

Something like
`new Carbon('last wednesday')`

Comment: There you go: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, `$startDate` and `$endDate` containing the date you want.

```
$date=\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::now()->previous('Wednesday');
$endDate=$date->toDateTimeString();
$interval = \Carbon\CarbonInterval::weeks(2);
$startDate=$date->sub($interval)->toDateTimeString();
dd($startDate,$endDate);
```